# Approach of how to put a GMGridView inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, cell, gmgridview, gmgridviewcell

i don't know how should i get a GMGridView (horizontal only) into a UITableViewCell, i tried adding as a subview but It gets messed up... any ideas?

the code is in fact simple...

```
HorizontalGridViewController *pics = [[HorizontalGridViewController alloc] init];
[pics setPicsArray: picsArray];
[cell addSubview:[pics view]];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the frame of the `gridViewController` to be something that is only inside the cell, otherwise it could be going completely outside the cell where it wouldn't show at all or it could be going inside then outside again and look completely wonky.